# Is there a limit on the size of the SVG point symbols in GeoServer?

Tags: geoserver, svg

I am adding an SVG icon on the map, but I got very small icon. I would like to get the icon size 30% or 50% larger than it is now.  I tried to scale the icon, but I think that GeoServer has a size limit for the icon and it cannot be too big.

I added this code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd">
<!-- Creator: CorelDRAW 2019 (64-Bit) -->
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xml:space="preserve" width="236px" height="283px" version="1.1" style="shape-rendering:geometricPrecision; text-rendering:geometricPrecision; image-rendering:optimizeQuality; fill-rule:evenodd; clip-rule:evenodd"
viewBox="0 0 236 283.2"
 xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
 xmlns:xodm="http://www.corel.com/coreldraw/odm/2003">
 <defs>
 <filter id="f1">
       <feColorMatrix result="matrixOut" in="offOut" type="matrix" values="0.2 0 0 0 0 0 0.2 0 0 0 0 0 0.2 0 0 0 0 0 1 0" />
      <feGaussianBlur result="blurOut" in="matrixOut" stdDeviation="5" />
      <feBlend in="SourceGraphic" in2="blurOut" mode="normal" />
 </filter>
  <style type="text/css">
   <![CDATA[
    .fil3 {fill:black}
    .fil1 {fill:#9FC53A}
    .fil2 {fill:#F29200}
    .fil0 {fill:white}
    .fil4 {fill:white; fill-rule:nonzero}
   ]]>
  </style>
 </defs>
 <g id="Слой_x0020_1">
  <metadata id="CorelCorpID_0Corel-Layer"/>
  <path class="fil0" d="M136.44 236.46c-1.13,3.41 -2.09,6.84 -3.39,10.2 -0.35,0.91 -0.74,1.8 -1.16,2.68 -2.84,5.98 -7.83,10.53 -14.79,10.53 -6.95,-0.01 -11.94,-4.55 -14.78,-10.53 -0.41,-0.88 -0.8,-1.77 -1.15,-2.68 -1.3,-3.36 -2.26,-6.79 -3.39,-10.2 -1.78,-4.43 -4.13,-8.59 -6.96,-12.42 -6.94,-9.37 -15.99,-17.33 -24.51,-24.93 -4.37,-3.75 -8.7,-7.55 -12.68,-11.37 -19.63,-17.9 -30.75,-43.05 -30.75,-69.64 0,-52.04 42.19,-94.23 94.23,-94.23 52.04,0 94.23,42.19 94.23,94.23 0,26.66 -11.18,51.87 -30.71,69.6 -4.1,3.93 -8.36,7.67 -12.53,11.24 -8.66,7.72 -17.76,15.72 -24.7,25.1 -2.84,3.83 -5.18,7.99 -6.96,12.42z" filter="url(#f1)"/>
  <path class="fil1" d="M127.08 233.04c-1.13,3.37 -2.03,6.68 -3.32,10.03 -0.27,0.68 -0.56,1.34 -0.87,2 -1.17,2.46 -2.97,4.86 -5.78,4.84 -2.82,0.02 -4.62,-2.38 -5.79,-4.84 -0.31,-0.66 -0.6,-1.32 -0.86,-2 -1.29,-3.35 -2.2,-6.66 -3.32,-10.03 -2.14,-5.38 -4.93,-10.36 -8.32,-14.93 -7.4,-10 -16.96,-18.48 -26.02,-26.56 -4.22,-3.62 -8.42,-7.3 -12.45,-11.17 -16.9,-15.41 -27.51,-37.6 -27.51,-62.28 0,-46.54 37.73,-84.27 84.27,-84.27 46.54,0 84.27,37.73 84.27,84.27 0,24.74 -10.66,46.99 -27.64,62.41 -3.99,3.82 -8.13,7.45 -12.27,10.99 -9.11,8.13 -18.67,16.61 -26.07,26.61 -3.39,4.57 -6.19,9.55 -8.32,14.93z"/>
  <path class="fil4" d="M117.11 49.62c37.82,0 68.48,30.66 68.48,68.48 0,37.82 -30.66,68.48 -68.48,68.48 -37.82,0 -68.48,-30.66 -68.48,-68.48 0,-37.82 30.66,-68.48 68.48,-68.48z"/>
  <g id="_2043580368">
   <path class="fil2" d="M144.61 93.79l-0.04 -0.03c-0.33,-0.32 -0.67,-0.62 -1,-0.91 -0.26,-0.23 -0.52,-0.45 -0.8,-0.66 -2.24,-1.78 -4.47,-2.83 -7.48,-3.12 -1.59,-0.2 -3.23,-0.13 -4.86,0.23 -0.8,0.17 -1.56,0.41 -2.3,0.7 -6.11,2.38 -9.45,8.24 -9.99,14.62 -0.05,0.59 -0.08,1.18 -0.08,1.77 0,0.72 0.03,1.43 0.1,2.15 0.74,8.11 5.51,14.95 10.68,20.92 4.58,5.29 9.41,9.43 14.59,14.05 1.03,0.92 2.24,2.06 3.3,2.89 0.44,0.33 0.69,0.49 0.95,0.48 0.25,0.01 0.51,-0.15 0.94,-0.48 1.06,-0.83 2.27,-1.97 3.31,-2.89 5.18,-4.62 10,-8.76 14.58,-14.05 5.18,-5.97 9.94,-12.81 10.69,-20.92 0.06,-0.72 0.09,-1.43 0.09,-2.15 0,-0.59 -0.02,-1.18 -0.08,-1.77 -0.54,-6.38 -3.88,-12.24 -9.99,-14.62 -0.73,-0.29 -1.5,-0.53 -2.3,-0.7 -1.63,-0.36 -3.26,-0.43 -4.85,-0.23 -3.02,0.29 -5.25,1.34 -7.49,3.12 -0.27,0.21 -0.54,0.43 -0.8,0.66 -0.33,0.29 -0.66,0.59 -1,0.91l-0.04 0.03c-1.04,1.05 -2.54,3.32 -3.06,4.76 -0.52,-1.44 -2.03,-3.71 -3.07,-4.76z"/>
   <path class="fil3" d="M93.63 116.61c-5.63,0 -13.46,0.15 -16.11,-5.31 -2.5,-5.15 -1.63,-13.43 1.52,-17.24 2.61,-3.15 10.1,-3.58 12.73,-2.67 1.71,0.59 1.92,1.56 1.91,3.63 -0.01,1.93 0.11,20.26 -0.05,21.59zm-8.65 1.13c-0.37,0.43 -2.51,0.81 -4.61,2.09 -1.38,0.86 -2.81,1.84 -3.9,3.05 -0.66,0.72 -1.15,1.14 -1.76,1.97 -3.53,4.76 -5.2,10.96 -7.41,16.39 -0.44,1.09 -1.29,3.15 -2.29,3.82 -0.8,0.5 -1.79,0.65 -2.87,0.66 -0.72,0 -2.24,-0.28 -2.71,0.31 -0.39,0.48 0.12,0.99 0.63,1.12 0.58,0.16 1.46,0.07 2.08,0.05 1.31,-0.02 2.65,-0.05 3.93,-0.07l8.06 0c0.41,-2.5 1.18,-5.31 1.83,-7.76 0.95,-3.5 1.98,-7.21 3.15,-10.64 1.13,-3.33 2.51,-6.13 5.34,-8.33 2.74,-2.14 5.93,-1.95 9.23,-1.95 0,7.29 -0.04,14.59 0,21.88 0,0.99 0.17,2.98 -0.11,3.82 -0.44,1.16 -2.42,1.26 -3.46,1.35 -0.89,0.08 -1.76,0.06 -2.63,0.13 -0.5,0.04 -1.3,0.2 -1.28,0.86 0.02,0.75 2.48,0.7 2.98,0.68 0.81,-0.03 1.61,-0.11 2.42,-0.12 5.17,0.03 10.35,0.08 15.52,0.09 0.6,0 1.51,-0.03 1.7,-0.75 0.1,-0.4 -0.35,-0.64 -0.7,-0.69 -0.48,-0.08 -1.42,-0.05 -1.97,-0.09 -1.01,-0.06 -3.54,-0.21 -4.07,-1.2 -0.33,-0.76 -0.14,-39.4 -0.14,-43.28 0,-2.06 -0.23,-6.74 0.15,-8.46 0.44,-1.73 2.17,-1.74 3.67,-1.74 0.71,0 2.42,0.12 2.99,-0.27 0.32,-0.22 0.34,-0.98 -0.22,-1.23 -0.67,-0.29 -2.56,-0.14 -3.35,-0.11 -1.83,0.08 -3.59,0.18 -5.43,0.24 -8.86,0.32 -22.79,-2.25 -29.08,4.43 -3.82,4.05 -4.71,11.29 -1.67,17.2 1.33,2.6 3.56,4.09 6.26,5.03 4.12,1.43 9.1,1.05 9.72,1.52z"/>
  </g>
 </g>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 2):

assuming that you want to publish your map via WMS, you could use SLD to style your layer.
You can use the `<size>` element. You can find an example in the [GeoServer SLD Cookbook](https://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/styling/sld/cookbook/points.html). The Point as Graphic section should cover what you want.

Your SLD could look like this:

```
<sld:PointSymbolizer>
            <sld:Graphic>
                <sld:ExternalGraphic>
                    <sld:OnlineResource xlink:type="simple"
                                        xlink:href="myIcon.svg" />
                    <sld:Format>image/svg+xml</sld:Format>
                </sld:ExternalGraphic>
                <sld:Size>12</sld:Size>
            </sld:Graphic>
</sld:PointSymbolizer>
```

Comment: The size will default to 6px if you don't specify it.